# Qt creating new window from my mainwindow

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

so I have made 2 windows, and from my main window I am trying to create a new window when I click on a button

The function I have connected with the button looks like this

```
void MainWindow::ProfileCreation()
{
CreateProfile cProfile;

cProfile.show();
cProfile.raise();
cProfile.activateWindow();
}
```

But when I try to click on the button, the window open for like 0,5-1 sec and then closes down again

If i do this in my main.cpp file, where i create MainWindow, it works without problems and shows the window

What should I do to make the window keep showing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cProfile` is a local variable, I don't perfectly know QT but I guess as the variable is destroyed when `ProfileCreation` exits, the window automatically closes. You'll have to preserve `cProfile`, either as a class member, a global variable or created on the heap as a pointer.

Comment: Oh yea I found that out myself by now ,but i then ran into another problem, but thanks anyway :) 

I now have a new problem though, I can't seem to transfer information i fill in one window to the other, any ideas to how i can do this?

Comment: @Sumsar1812 add Q_OBJECT macro to the CProfile class and use the signal/slot system to communicate with it

Answer (score 1):

If your second window is a dialog you can hide the first one and execute the second one.

```
this->hide();
dialog mainDialog;
dialog.setModal(true);
dialog.exec();
```